# Is there an idiomatic way to constraint the use of shared_ptr::reset

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

If a call to `shared_ptr::reset` does not appear in my code for a specific reference counted object, then it would be nice if this could be made explicit and enforceable at compile time.

Is there a standard way to do this?

CLARIFICATION: It is ok if the shared_ptr itself calls reset privately. I just want to make sure I do not call it in my code.

**UPDATE: @Brian actually answered it in a comment. `const auto p = make_shared...` solves the problem for what I declare and if otheres make a non const copy its their problem. I never saw anyone declaring a `shared_ptr` as const hence somehow I did not think about it.**

Comment: Can you elaborate on your situation? I suspect that there might be a better overall solution to your problem than trying to do what you're specifying here.

Comment: It's normal usage to never call this function, so it is not clear to me what you are asking

Comment: If you don't want to call it, don't call it. Presumably you don't want to call it because it would make your program incorrect; this is what code review and tests are for. Perhaps you have a leaky abstraction - should this `shared_ptr`be a private member variable of some higher-level class?

Comment: @M.M, exactly this is normal usage and I want to guarantee that only this normal usage happens. A few years ago I got a big surprise when someone else called reset for me unexpectedly.

Comment: Well, `p.reset()` is the same as `p = std::shared_ptr<T>()`, so it sounds like you really want your `shared_ptr` to be `const`.

Comment: If your goal is to make sure the pointer is not reset to *null* then maybe `gsl::not_null` from the `CppCoreGuidelines Guideline Support Library` may be worth looking at? https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-nullptr

Answer (score 1):

You cannot forcibly prevent someone from calling a particular public interface function of a class. That's why it's a *public* interface.

It's not clear what you mean by:

> a call to `shared_ptr::reset` does not appear in my code for a specific reference counted object

The confusing part is what "specific reference counted object" means. You could be talking about a specific instance object of a `shared_ptr<T>`. In that case, if you want to prevent someone from resetting that particular instance, you can declare it to be a `const` object. This will also prevent copy/move assignment to it, which can have the same effect.

That doesn't work if the "specific reference counted object" refers to the `T` held by the pointer, rather than `shared_ptr<T>`. Someone can take a `const` object and copy it to a non-`const` object easily enough. They won't be able to reset the `const` pointer, but they can still reset a pointer that points to that `T`.

If `shared_ptr<T>::reset` offends you enough, you could derive (privately) a new class from `shared_ptr`, then inherit the interfaces you want except for `reset`. Then you use your derived class rather than the actual `shared_ptr`.

Of course, you'll also need to get rid of the copy/move assignment operators, since they can be used to have the same effect as `reset`. And if you have such a `non_rebindable_shared_ptr`, then it shouldn't have a default constructor, since creating an empty one would be useless.

Comment: My point is that calling reset is not a usual case. Hence it would be a bad idea if everyone derives his own special `shared_ptr` for the usual case. From the answers so far I believe there is no standard way to do it. So my question should rather be, why does no one feel the need for a shared pointer that guarantees that the referenced counted object is not changed unexpectedly to another object.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: "*My point is that calling reset is not a usual case.*" According to whom? It's part of the API; who decides whether using it is "a usual case" or not? "*So my question should rather be, why does no one feel the need for a shared pointer that guarantees that the referenced counted object is not changed unexpectedly to another object.*" Because that's how value types work in C++. If you have non-`const` access to them, then you can change them. If you want objects with unmodifiable state, then use a functional language.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: Or to put it another way, the way C++ spells "you can't change this value after it is initialized" is `const`. `T *const` is a pointer whose address can't be changed after it is initialized. `const shared_ptr<T>` is the same, only with a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I want my shared pointers to reference count and delete my object when the last shared pointer goes out of scope. I assume the reference counters are mutable, hence I assume a shared_ptr being const should not be an issue. A shared pointer class with a compile time assert ensuring its instances are const may be what I need.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: "*A shared pointer class with a compile time assert ensuring its instances are const may be what I need.*" Why not just remove the parts of the interface that allow you to modify it? If you're already talking about a new class, it's better to make it clear what its interface is than to tell people that they have to declare them `const`. And it's also not a thing you can do anyway; you cannot *force* people to declare objects as `const`. And there's no way to `static_assert` on it either.

Comment: @Nicola. Yes, the assert was a bad idea.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: "*I was thinking of an easy std::shared_ptr derived class but no, that's not possible or not easy.*" Yes, it is. It's simply private inheritance, some `= delete`s for a few offending methods, and inheriting the interfaces you want to expose. Your biggest problem is the non-member functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158282/discussion-between-patrick-fromberg-and-nicol-bolas).